# NServiceBus SetHeader In Catch of Handler

Tags: nservicebus

We are using a try catch in our message handler, which we realize is against the recommended best practices of not handling exceptions.  That said, I have been asked to identify the last retry and send a message to another queue in a suppressed transaction.  The sending of the message is working however, I am calling message.SetHeader (also tried Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers[EsbService.FirstLevelRetriesHeader] = currentFirstLevelRetryAttempt.ToString();) to implement my own tracking of the retry attempts.  Basically looking to write the an incrementing number in the header and look to see when it reaches a specific value to trigger the send of the message to another queue.  It seems to write to it, but when the the message is processed again, it is never present.  I am using transactions, so is it possible that the changes are getting rolled back when I throw the exception.  I tried writing to the header in a suppressed transaction as well and that did not work.

Is there any way to update a header while still letting the exception bubble up to NSB.

Comment: Are you trying to count first level retries or second level retries or both?